# Fields_for, how to use this data in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4.2

I'm lost onto how to use the data I get from using fields_for in rails. The array looks like this:
`"order"=>{"order_item"=>{"1"=>{"quantity"=>"1"}, "2"=>{"quantity"=>"1"}}}`

But I'm unsure on how to grab and use this data in a controller. For your information, I need to find the OrderItem by the id:
`.. "order_item"=>{"1 (<-- this number is the id!)" ..` and then update the quantity for that order_item.

I try to accept the params like this:

```
def order_params
    params.require(:order).permit( order_item_attributes: [ :quantity ])
  end
```

That should be correct, right?

in the controller I want to do something like this:

```
order_params[order_item_attributes].each do |item_id|
    @orderitem = OderItem.find_by(id: item_id)
    @orderitem.update(quantity: item_id[:quantity])
#... etc
```

I know the last code isn't correct, but I hope it helps you understand what I'm trying to do. I can find very little documentation on the fields_for and how to handle the data. Help would be welcome!

EDIT1:
This is what the view looks like

```
= form_for @order, :url => admin_update_order_path, :html => {:method => :post} do |f|
  %table.detail_table
    %tr
      %th
        %b Product
      %th
        %b Prijs
      %th
        %b Aantal
      %th
        %b Totaal
      %th
        %b Opties
    - @order_items.each do |item|
      %tr
        %td
          = item.product.name
          %br
          - x = 0
          - item.product.product_attachments.each do |attachment|
            -if item.product.id == attachment.product_id && x == 0
              = image_tag attachment.image_url(:small)
              - x = 1
        %td= number_to_currency((item.product.price), :unit => "€", :separator => ",", :delimiter => ' ')
        %td
          = f.fields_for :order_items do |item_form|
            = item_form.text_field :quantity, :class => "item_field"
        %td= number_to_currency((item.product.price*item.quantity), :unit => "€", :separator => ",", :delimiter => ' ')
        %td= link_to 'Verwijderen', item, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Weet u zeker dat u dit product uit dit order wilt verwijderen?' }
  %br/
  = f.submit
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at your params you are not passing in `order_items_attributes` you are passing `order_item`. Maybe if you change this you will have better luck.

The best way to test this is to fire up the rails console and copy your params into the console and see if you can get it working there. If you don't come right there then it wont work in the front end.

Also make sure that you have [accepts_nested_attributes_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) setup on your order model for order_items.

Edit 2

```
= f.fields_for item, index: item.id do |item_form| 
    = item_form.text_field
```

This above should be

```
= f.fields_for :order_items do |item_form| 
    = item_form.text_field
```

Your order model should have

```
has_many :order_items
accepts_nested_attributes_for :order_items
```

Your controller should permit params like so

```
def order_params
    params.require(:order).permit( order_items_attributes: [:id :quantity])
end
```

Also if you want to get really funky with accepts_nested_attributes_for you should look into a gem called [cocoon](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon)

Comment: Hmm, thought it was the `accepts_nested_attributes_for`. Added this now, but they still aren't accepted: `Unpermitted parameter: order_item`

Comment: Yes that makes sense. You must have something in your form incorrect. Since the params you are passing from your form is order[order_item] when it should be something like order[order_items_attributes].

Comment: I think I got it working now by replacing `order_items_attributes: [:quantity]` with `order_item: [:quantity]`. I see what you meant now. I'm not really declaring any `order_item_attributes` in the form, so I'm unsure about this. Thank you!

Comment: No you are probably doing something like `f.fields_for :order_items do |oi|` ? This should pass items as order_items_attributes. Don't think I can help too much more without seeing more code.

Comment: `= f.fields_for item, index: item.id do |item_form|
    = item_form.text_field :quantity, :class => "item_field"` this is the code. Would it be possible to have the array result in something like this:
`"order"=>{"order_item"=>{"id"=> "1"=>{"quantity"=>"1"},"id"=> "2"=>{"quantity"=>"1"}}}`?

Comment: This helps a lot, but now I see why I did the `index: item.id` in the fields for. I updated the question with the complete view code. I try to add the text field in a table cell. Using the `fields_for` code you suggested in your edit 2 gives me 4 text fields for 2 items, 2 in each `td`.

Comment: Change `= f.fields_for :order_items do |item_form|` to  `= f.fields_for :order_items, item do |item_form|` that should sort your out.